# How do I limit a down counter so that it counts from 3 to 0?

Tags: logic-gates, clock, flipflop, counter

I've been studying binary counters and learned how to build an up counter that starts at 0 and counts to a set value before resetting. Now, I need to learn how to build a down counter that starts at a set value and counts down to zero.

So far, I have a counter that counts from 7 to 0. I've tried limiting the down counter in the same way as the up counter, but it doesn't work.

[image: down counter circuit]

How do I wire the circuit so that it starts at 3 and not 7?

Comment: How many bits do you need to represent 3 in binary? How many bits does your counter have? Does it need that many?

Answer (score 0):

The flip-flops need set and clear inputs to "preload a number.

Whether counting up-or down, a starting number can be preloaded.
Something like [this](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G74.pdf):

[image]